# Referencing an object in another class with Inherit attributes

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb.net for an MT2070 scanner. I have referenced objects in other classes before, but not when that other class is "Inheriting" something. How do I reference something in a class that inherits attributes from another class?

I have this class:

```
Public Class MainScreen
Inherits ListScreen

   Sub AddToInventory(ByVal barcode As String)
   '...code here
   end sub
```

And I would like to reference the object "AddToInventory" in another class. I thought this would work:

```
Public Class MainForm
Inherits ListForm

   Sub RunTest
   Dim w As MainScreen = New MainScreen
   w.AddToInventory("10010")
```

But I get this Error: Argument not specified for parameter 'listform' of 'public sub new(listform as listform)'

Please advise, what am I missing? How do I reference "AddToInventory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error has got nothing to do with inheritance, nor with your `AddToInventory` method. You are simply failing to call the constructor of `MainScreen` with its required arguments (apparently `listform` is required).

Comment: Please advise, what do I add? I tried it a few other ways without success:

Comment: Sub RunTest
   Dim w As MainScreen = New (MainScreen as listscreen)
   w.AddToInventory("10010")

Comment: Sub RunTest
   Dim w As MainScreen inherits listscreen = New MainScreen
   w.AddToInventory("10010")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Konrad - your insight led me to the answer. I needed just a small modification:

```
Public Class MainForm
Inherits ListForm

  Sub RunTest
  Dim w As MainScreen = New MainScreen(me)
  w.AddToInventory("10010")
```